# Reading a file path from property and then reading the file idiomatic Scala

Tags: scala

I want to read in the path of a file from configureation and then read the file in an idomatic Scala way. This is the code I have so far:

```
val key: Option[String] = {
  val publicKeyPath: Option[String] = conf.getString("bestnet.publicKeyFile")
  publicKeyPath match {
    case Some(path) => {
      Future {
        val source = fromFile(s"./$path")
        val key: String = source.getLines.toIterable.drop(1).dropRight(1).mkString
        source.close()
        key
      } onComplete {
        case Success(key) => Success(key)
        case Failure(t) => None
      }
    }
    case None => None
  }
}
```

However this is not working since Im getting the error `Expression of type Unit does not conform to Option[String]`

What am I getting wrong and is my approach idiomatic Scala or should it be done in some other way?

Comment: Does `getString` return an `Option[T]`?

Comment: Updated question with more types

Comment: Future's "onComplete" returns Unit. What you probably want to do is to "map" over the Future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the contents as `String` there is no need to use a `Future`. E.g. the following would do:

```
val key: Option[String] = {
  val publicKeyPath: Option[String] = conf.getString("bestnet.publicKeyFile")
  publicKeyPath match {
    case Some(path) =>
      val source = fromFile(s"./$path")
      val key: String = source.getLines.toIterable.drop(1).dropRight(1).mkString
      source.close()
      Some(key)
    case None =>
      None
  }
}
```

The pattern of transforming the value of a `Some(_)` can be done more idiomatic using the higher-level function `map`, i.e.:

```
val key: Option[String] = {
  val publicKeyPath = conf.getString("bestnet.publicKeyFile")

  publicKeyPath.map(path => {
      val source = fromFile(s"./$path")
      val key = source.getLines.toIterable.drop(1).dropRight(1).mkString
      source.close()
      key
  })
}
```

A more idiomatic way to do resource management (i.e. closing the `Source`) is by using the "Loan Pattern". For example:

```
def using[A](r: Resource)(f: Resource => A): A = try {
    f(r)
} finally {
    r.dispose()
}

val key: Option[String] = {
  val publicKeyPath = conf.getString("bestnet.publicKeyFile")

  publicKeyPath.map(path =>
      using(fromFile(s"./$path"))(source =>
          source.getLines.toIterable.drop(1).dropRight(1).mkString
      )
  )
}
```

Scala is a flexible language and it is not uncommon to define such an abstraction in user-land (whereas in Java, the `using` abstraction is a language feature).

If you need non-blocking parallel code you should return a `Future[String]` instead of an `Option[String]`. This complicates the automatic resource management, since code is executed at a different time. Anyway, this should give you some pointers for improving your code.